# Antiword binary /usr/local/bin/antiword does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, installation

I am downloading cats open source ats software.When I ran installtest.php this error occurred:

> Antiword binary /usr/local/bin/antiword does not exist.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Have you tried installing antiword?

Comment: Do I require it because once I was able to run it without antiword

Comment: No idea, I'm only suggesting a solution